# Scale of Paizo's Pathfinder/Starfinder pawns and paper minis

Tags: creature-size, battle-map, miniatures

I've been a fan of [Paizo's paper minis](https://paizo.com/companies/pathfinderPaperMinis). Ever since I printed out the first batch, I noticed that they follow the [28mm scale for miniatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_model_(gaming)) - i.e. in most paper minis representing adult humanoids, the distance from the feet to the eyes is about 28mm.

The 28mm scale is consistent with the Pathfinder tactical grid (5 feet to the inch = 1:60 scale), [DnD5e materials](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101986/what-size-is-the-standard-grid-used-when-playing-dd-5e), and most plastic/metal miniatures (e.g. [Reaper minis](https://www.reapermini.com/Miniatures/Pathfinder/)), 3D-printed dungeon tiles and furniture that I'm aware of.

(By contrast, GURPS hex grids use a scale of one yard to the inch or ≈1:36.5 or ≈46mm from feet to eyes)

Recently, I've got access to the [Starfinder beginner box](https://paizo.com/starfinder/beginnerbox), which features Paizo's cardboard pawns. To my surprise, the cardboard pawns follow a different (bigger) scale, which seems to be 40mm from feet to eyes on a 28mm-wide base:

[image: paper minis and cardboard pawns side to side]

Even when the size of the bases are the same (25mm diameter), they look obviously different.

This poses a few questions in my mind:

- Do the cardboard pawns from Paizo follow a known, consistent scale?
- As a GM, how can I minimize the visual clash when mixing 25/28mm-scale minis and bigger-scale cardboard pawns?

Comment: Pretty sure every miniature I bought and painted back in the late 1970s was 25 mm scale.  That was just before or about the time Ral Partha opened, so things have change some since.

Comment: RE: "What's the rationale for the change in scale between Paizo's paper minis and Paizo's cardboard pawns?" and RE: "Are there any plastic/metal miniatures for 5-feet-to-the-inch tactical grids which do not follow a 28mm scale?" Sadly, I suspect site policy prevents answering these aspects of this question, the former because it's asking for reasons why the designers make a certain choice (designer reasons are off-topic), and the latter because it asks for an unbounded list (shopping questions are off-topic). The middle issue (without its second question) is probably fine, though. `:-)`

Comment: Well, I haven't spent much time in RPG.SE, so I apologize about the on-topic/off-topic-ness of the question :-) I can happily cross-post in another SE site re: design aspects. Re: 3rd question, I'm asking for any counterexamples rather than a shopping list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about author's intent, topic declared off topic on this site.

Comment: O, no need to apologize! It wasn't, like, a reprimand, and I'm not a moderator or anything anyway. User to user, I just wanted you to understand why the question may end up on hold. Like I said, *Is the scale used for* Starfinder *cardboard pawns unique?* is a probably by itself a fine question; it's just that the site doesn't handle the other two parts. (You can if you want read more about site policy on [designer reasons](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/8610) and [shopping](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8217/8610), which is a synonym for *What're more like this?* questions.)

Comment: Gotcha :-) I've been on the giving end of "this is off-topic" on other SE sites and I do appreciate your understanding and the site policy two links. Let me try and rephrase the question a bit.

Comment: The two questions you have are quite different are they not? It would probably be better to ask them seperatly, so you can get proper answers for both. Feel free to link between them if it helps for context.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I guess so; I'll try to rephrase again tomorrow